# Looking for wheel file for pythonRLSA that will work with python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to look for a wheel file for pythonRLSA that will work with Python 3.11, but pypi.org only has one which is for Python 3.7

I googled and asked Bard and ChatGPT, but to no avail.
[screenshot of the available wheel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyhVj.png)

The link to pythonRLSA in pypi is below:

https://pypi.org/project/pythonRLSA/#files

Comment: If there isn't one on PyPi, you probably have to build it yourself. Running `pip install` will include some instructions about how to set-up your environment to do that.

Comment: if i create a virtual environment for python 3.11, and i create a wheel file for pythonRLSA with that, would that make the wheel file compatible with python 3.11?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, wheels are available till `python 3.7`

`pythonRLSA` works on python `3.5, 3.6, 3.7`

I would suggest you to download `python 3.7` from python.org separately to use `pythonRLSA`

Here is the github link: https://github.com/Vasistareddy/pythonRLSA

https://pypi.org/project/pythonRLSA/#description